# Compare tables A and B, and if there are duplicate values, insert the code defined in table B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare the following two tables.
After comparing the words in table B with the words in table A, I want to put the code of the overlapping value in the empty Code column of table A.
Since it is not case-sensitive, I want to change all words to lower case before proceeding with the comparison.
If they don't match, I want to disable code injection.

There are about 10000 pieces of data

**I haven't been able to solve this for 2 days. Please help me!!**

Table A

| Code | Title |
| --- | --- |
|  | Cholera |
|  | Intestinal infection due to other Vibrio |
|  | Typhoid fever |
|  | Typhoid peritonitis |
|  | Paratyphoid fever |
|  | Infections due to other Salmonella |
|  | Salmonella enteritis |

Table B

| Code | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1A00 | Cholera |
| 1A01 | Intestinal infection due to other Vibrio |
| 1A02 | Intestinal infections due to Shigella |
| 1A07 | Typhoid fever |
| 1A07.0 | Typhoid peritonitis |
| 1A07.Y | Other specified typhoid fever |
| 1A07.Z | Typhoid fever, unspecifiedw |

result Table

| Code | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1A00 | Cholera |
| 1A01 | Intestinal infection due to other Vibrio |
| 1A07 | Typhoid fever |
| 1A07.0 | Typhoid peritonitis |
|  | Paratyphoid fever |
|  | Infections due to other Salmonella |
|  | Salmonella enteritis |

Answer (score 0):

First create a new column with the lower case

then just do a standard merge

```
df3 = pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2,
    how = 'left',
    on = 'cat',
    suffixes = ['_x', '']
    )[['Code', 'Title_x']].rename(columns = {'Title_x': 'Title'})
```

Comment: what's mean df1, df2?

Comment: Table A and B...